# Is overflow:hidden to fit a width a hack - is there an alternative?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow

Is overflow:hidden to fit a width a hack? We have a responsive website that uses overflow:hidden in conjunction with width:100% to set the layout properly. However, any new feature that we add has issues.

For example, we implemented a custom html drop down. The drop down is partially hidden when expanded outside the container.

Is there a proper way to get this to work without having to redo the styles for the entire page?

The behavior I'm trying to describe is used in #4 in this article
http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/5-useful-css-tricks-for-responsive-design/comment-page-2

Comment: Yes, you could call it a hack, since it was never really designed for that purpose.

Comment: Does it matter? It's a specific requirement of the CSS spec, so it's not like it's ever going to stop behaving that way. But you're probably asking the wrong question. You would do better to ask about the specific issues you get when you add the new features.

Comment: If a site is designed fluidly and responsively, using overflow-y:hidden, won't be a problem. Generally, with the menu, it's handy to detect whether or not it will leave the container (whatever that is) and set a class and then adjust: http://stackoverflow.com./a/11525189/1004312

Comment: You can also remove it from the site's css and see what happens. It may create horizontal scrolling then see what is causing that and adjust it to not do that. I tend to make a test page and start by remove all and adding one chunk at a time. Because even though you've got a fluid site, using overflow-y:hidden on IOS will cause a zoom on focus of an input and the page will shift over the length of the leftover space. It's hard to explain.

Comment: When I remove it, the entire site is completely messed up.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `overflow:hidden` is not to clear floats per se, but to control child content containment by establishing a new [**block formatting context**](http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/)(BFC) flow root, one feature of BFCs is float containment.

[**More on BFCs from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

> A block formatting context is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a
>   Web page. It is the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs
>   and in which floats interact with each other.
>
> A block formatting context contains everything inside of the element
>   creating it that is not also inside a descendant element that creates
>   a new block formatting context.
>
> Block formatting contexts are important for the positioning (see
>   float) and clearing (see clear) of floats. The rules for positioning
>   and clearing of floats apply only to things within the same block
>   formatting context. Floats do not affect the layout of things in other
>   block formatting contexts, and clear only clears past floats in the
>   same block formatting context.

Technically the way to clear floats is to use `clear`, this will also mean you dont have to rely on using `overflow:hidden` thereby removing your menu cropping issue.

You can, for example, have an element after your floated elements with `clear` set on it - another alternative would be to use a [**clearfix**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) (also, [**here**](http://themergency.com/css-clearfix-demystified/)). A clearfix uses a psuedo element to apply the relevant clear.

[**More on `clear` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

> The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them.
>
> [...]
>
> The floats that are relevant to be cleared are the
>   earlier floats within the same block formatting context.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this doesn't help me as I don't think i presented my question clearly enough. I edited the question.

Comment: clearfix hack did it. I don't want to set overflow:hidden, because I have a popup type element inside that would then crop incorrectly to the element dimensions (it's supposed to float above it).... Thanks very much!